# Подскажите словарь для чтения технической документации по Android разработке

Tags: java, android, терминология, документация

Знание английского у меня на не очень высоком уровне, а документацию читать нужно. Так как слова там применяются в основном относящиеся к разработке, хотелось иметь словарь основных таких английских слов для выучивания и дальнейшего применения при чтении технической документации

Comment: Да сам себе создай словарь, пополняй и выучивай.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не думаю что вы сможете где-то найти словарь, необходимый вам. Но могу дать несколько советов.

1. Как писалось выше, завести себе свой собственный словарик (блокнот или приложение на телефоне), куда вы будете выписывать слова.
2. Старайтесь чаще читать статьи на английском. На самом деле технический английский он достаточно однообразен и для того чтоб более и менее комфортно читать документацию нужно нет так много усилий.
3. Есть много альтернативных русских ресурсов по разным темам. Например очень хороший ресурс это 
   https://startandroid.ru/ru/
   Там конечно очень не мало устаревшего материала, но большинство вещей являются основами и не меняются с годами. Ну и парень продолжает развивать свой курс.
4. Ну и никто не отменял Гугл переводчик. Он конечно часто переводит криво, но для общего понимания этого часто достаточно.

Ну а в целом здесь только самому. Читать, читать и ещё раз читать на английском.

Comment: Спасибо большое)